# UPDATED: Deserialise Nested JSON with JSON Utility Unity 5.4

Tags: unity, c#, oop, json

I am trying to deserialise a JSON with Unity 5.4's JSON utility ([here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/130044/updated-deserialise-nested-json-with-json-utility-unity-5-4)).

This is what my JSON looks like:

```
{
    "series": [
        {,
            "points":[ 
                {"ts":"1473850836254","value":"11.27"}, 
                {"ts":"1473851256637","value":"6.44"}
            ]
        }
     ]
}
```

I am trying to access the values in "points" by calling something like: data.series.points[0].ts

```
void Start(){
    IncomingData data = IncomingData.CreateFromJSON(jsonResponse.text); // **error 1**
    print("Series point length" + data.series.points.Count);
    print("Series point 0" + data.series.points[0].ts); // **error 2**
}
```

//----------------------------------------- classes -------------------------

```
[System.Serializable]
public class IncomingData
{
    public Series series;
    public static IncomingData CreateFromJSON(string json)
    {   
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<IncomingData>(json);
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Series
{
    public List<Points> points = new List<Points> { };
}


[System.Serializable]
public class Points
{
    public int ts;
    public int value;
}
```

**Errors**

1. keystr == NULL UnityEngine.JsonUtility:FromJson(String)
2. Unexpected node type. UnityEngine.JsonUtility:FromJson(String)
3. ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range. Parameter name: index

I think it has something to do with how I embed the classes within each other - I am not really good at OOP ...

Comment: Please do not double post. And do not accept an answer if it's not the most useful; in this case if you still have the issue, it means it has not been the most useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON firstly is faulty and secondly does not match the data model.
To break down your JSON:

```
{
    "series": [
        {,
            "points":[
                {
                    "ts": "1473850836254",
                    "value": "11.27"
                },
                {
                    "ts": "1473851256637",
                    "value": "6.44"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Do you see the problems?

1. There is a `,` right after the first `{` bracket in `series`.
2. `series` is an array and not an object like in your C# object model.

To fix these errors and make your JSON compatible with the C# object model, remove the `[]` brackets for `series` and the leading comma:

```
{
    "series": {
        "points":[
            {
                "ts": "1473850836254",
                "value": "11.27"
            },
            {
                "ts": "1473851256637",
                "value": "6.44"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Also, change your data type of `value` in the `points` class to `double`, otherwise your values won't parse or will be truncated (I don't know how JSON Utility handles this). Your JSON should be valid and parse without errors.

Comment: Pasting you JSON into a formatter like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ can easily help you find faults.

Comment: @BackFromExcile: Series is an array with a couple of objects, including **points**. I just removed the other key/value pairs for simplicity, but missed the random comma while deleting.

Comment: What you suggests does work - if I run through the text and remove the **[]** on both ends. But it doesn't solve it for the case that I need the other key/value pairs in series ....